# Can't set geary email client as default email client

Tags: 16.04, email, default-programs, geary

I've had some problem with my previous Ubuntu 16.04 so I decided to make a fresh install.. however now I have a problem with Geary Email - I can't set it as a default email client. The only option available is Thunderbird.

Any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: How did you installed Geary?

Comment: @CelticWarrior sudo apt install geary.

Comment: If so, it should be there.

Comment: @CelticWarrior yup it should but it isn't :). I uninstalled Thunderbird then uninstalled Geary just to install Geary again but nothing. Now the default email is completely empty.